# material ui textfield cannot editable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-design, material-ui

I use material UI and a field text of type TextField. But when I was seized in my field email, the seizure does not appear to the screen and the value does not change in the email field.It always remains the same value.

Handle change is not working. the value is not passing to the `handleChanges` remains the same value

```
<TextField fullWidth={true}
  className={classes.margin}
  label={<FormattedMessage id="LoginTemplate.email" defaultMessage="Email" />}
  id="email"
  ref="email"
  name="eamil"
  type="email"
  value={authentification.email}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

Here is the code. Correct me What is the issue in that
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the value change, you need to change a state (in the screen or external).

For instance (with bad performance but just to explain):
add to your cunstrunctor if exists:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    emailInputText: undefined //or empty string
  }
}
```

Then change `TextField` component `value` and `onChange` props to:

```
value={this.state.emailInputText}
onChange={(text) => this.setState({emailInputText: text})}
```

> I will consider to remove the `ref='email'`.